# Magento 2: Adding fields/attributes to product "Assigned Sources"

Tags: magento2, admin, stock, multi-source-inventory

A relatively new feature in Magento 2 is stock sources, where inventory can be held at multiple locations, like this:

[image: Magento 2 product stock source editor]

Our client wants to store the location of the product within each store (aisle and shelf). Is it possible to extend the source functionality to achieve this?

Comment: Im sure adding in two additional fields wouldn't be a big task initially you would need to extend dynamic field js and alter stock functionality to include the dependencies but im sure it wouldn't take too long

Comment: did you find any solution for this queries

Comment: @DeebanBabu I haven't yet. Instead I used an attribute on the product with a JSON-encoded object that has the key as the machine name of the source. Far from ideal, but it works for my purposes.